# regexp replace format all numbers the same in a string (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, regexp-replace

Lets say I have

"Hello this is 11 and i want 0032 but there is 013 and 5"

"Hello this is 0011 and i want 0032 but there is 0013 and 0005"

EDITED

Comment: you cannot have it for "any" length. the replacement will cause overflow.

Comment: So what if I need it for max 4 of them like this sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that a single `REGEXP_REPLACE` is sufficient for your task, but you can do it in 2 steps:

1. Add some 0-digits before any number so that is at least your desired length.
2. Delete leading 0-digits until you get your desired length

As code it looks like this:

```sql
SELECT 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(
    REGEXP_REPLACE('Hello this is 11 and i want 0032 but there is 013 and 5'
                  ,'(\d+)','000\1') -- Add three 0-digits to any number
                ,'0+(\d{4})','\1') -- Remove all 0-digits prior to the last 4 digits of any number
  FROM dual
```

Result:

> Hello this is 0011 and i want 0032 but there is 0013 and 0005